# Vim folding on syntax for R

Tags: r, vim, folding

I'm working with vim on my linux machine and need code folding to work for R.  I have the Vim-R-plusing2  installed to enable passing code from vim into an R session, but the folding does not work when foldmethod=syntax.  How do I get folding for R working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What to do:**

You need to add the following code to your vimrc file:

```
  let r_syntax_folding = 1
```

**Why it works:**

This option changes how the Vim-R plugin loads.

This code is copied from `syntax/vim.r` and shows how the setting above changes what code is run:

```
" Error
if exists("g:r_syntax_folding")
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/(/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/)/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rBraceError,rCurlyError fold
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/{/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/}/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rBraceError,rParenError fold
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/\[/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/]/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rCurlyError,rParenError fold
else
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/(/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/)/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rBraceError,rCurlyError
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/{/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/}/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rBraceError,rParenError
  syn region rRegion matchgroup=Delimiter start=/\[/ matchgroup=Delimiter end=/]/ transparent contains=ALLBUT,rError,rCurlyError,rParenError
endif
```

Quoting from the help

> 10.8. Fold setup~
>
> Vim has several methods of folding
> text (see |fold-methods| and
> |fold-commands|). To enable the syntax
> method of folding for R files, put in
> your |vimrc|:
>
> > let r_syntax_folding = 1
>
> With the above option, Vim will load R
> files with all folds closed. If you
> prefer to start editing files with all
> folds open, put in your |vimrc|:

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you.  That was not actually the problem but you post told me what was.  Comparing what was in your answer to what was in my code I found that the `syn region` lines omitted the fold option at the end.  So folding wasn't turned on for those regions. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar, but referring to [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828606/vim-markdown-folding), anyway you may find some useful info there.

You may try even `:help folding`  for detailed descriptions.