# How to set the default to unfolded when you open a file?

Tags: vim, file-io, default, unfold

In my `.vimrc` I've put `set foldmethod=syntax` to enable folding of methods etc. However, I don't like the default that everytime I open a file, the whole thing is folded. Is there a way to enable `foldmethod`, yet have files unfolded when I open them?

Comment: I found this [article](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file) helpful to pick the right answer.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
set foldlevel=99
```

should open all folds, regardless of method used for folding. With `foldlevel=0` all folded, `foldlevel=1` only somes, ... higher numbers will close fewer folds.

Comment: but this will lead to a problem: pressing `zm` will not close all folds, unless you enter it 99 times

Comment: You could also `set nofoldenable`, which temporarily disables folding when you open the file, but all folds are restored as soon as you hit `zc`

Comment: To set the exact foldlevel you can use `:autocmd BufWinEnter * let &foldlevel = max(map(range(1, line('$')), 'foldlevel(v:val)'))` (taken from [an answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/567352)).

Comment: @bitboxer _"but this will lead to a problem: pressing zm will not close all folds"_ Use `zM` to close all folds.

Comment: To expand on wisbucky's reply, `99` is not a problem since `zM` indeed completely corrects its effects. See `:help foldlevel` and `:help zm`. `foldlevel=0` is a buffer value, defaulting to `0`, and easily reset, as witbucky points out, with `zM`. To add to 79E09796's great idea, `zi` is also nice, inverting `foldenable`, which remembers your fold choices.

Comment: @79E09796 You should move your comment to an answer of its own.

Comment: For anyone using Lua to configure: `vim.wo.foldlevel = 99`

Answer (score 71):

You can put this in your `.vimrc`:
`au BufRead * normal zR`

It declares an automatic command (`au`), triggered when a buffer is read (`BufRead`), matching all files (`*`) and executes the `zR` (opens all folds) command in normal mode.

Comment: For some reason this only partially unfolded the file. I had to use `BufWinEnter` instead.

Comment: just out of curiousity what is the opposite to `zR`

Comment: nvm, it's `zM` to close ALL the folds

Comment: Better with:`if has("autocmd") ... endif`

Answer (score 32):

```
set nofoldenable
```

Adding this to your `.vimrc` will temporarily disable folding when you open the file, but folds can still be restored with `zc`

Comment: Useful - but when you zc a fold it then hides all other folds also all-at-once.  I think i like personally defaulting to foldlevel=99 as it keeps 'zc' then localized to individual chunk you are looking at when invoked.

Answer (score 13):

In `.vimrc` add an autocmd for `BufWinEnter` to open all folds automatically like this:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent! :%foldopen!
```

That tell vim to execute the `silent :%foldopen!` after opening `BunWinEnter` event (see [`:h BufWinEnter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWinEnter)). The `silent %foldopen!` will execute [`foldopen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldopen%27) on the whole buffer thanks to the `%` and will open all folds recursively because of the `!`. Any eventual error message will be suppressed by [`silent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3asilent). (You could get error messages like `E490: No fold found` if the buffer actually didn't contain any fold yet)

Note: You could use `BufRead`  instead of `BufWinEnter` but then if the file has a modeline that enables the folding that will override this autocmd. I mean `BufRead` autocmds run before the modeline is processed and `BufWinEnter` will run them after. I find the later to be more useful

Comment: Why not just use a modeline that set different fold options per file?

Comment: using `autocmd` here allows to open all folds for *all files*  using a modeline it just to apply to that file and assumes that you can modify the file (it could be a read only file). The modeline would look like `# vim: set foldlevel=99` at the top or bottom of the file

Comment: How can this be achieved in Lua?

Answer (score 10):

You can add

```
set foldlevelstart=99
```

to your .vimrc file, and it will start editing any new file with all folds open.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is an actual dedicated setting in vim that does exactly what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a way to have it display unfolded as soon as it is opened, you can use `set foldlevelstart=99` as a lot of answers explained.

But, if you just want to see them unfolded, you can just press `zi` and it will unfold everything. Another, `zi` will close them back.

Answer (score 0):

You could map it to keys to enable it.
For example,

```
nmap ,f :set foldmethod=syntax<CR>
```

Then while in normal mode hit the ",f" key combination

Answer (score 0):

You can open unfolded file when you put `set nofoldenable` into your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 0):

`autocmd BufReadPost * silent! :%foldopen!`

This worked best for me. After a buffer gets opened all folds are opened. This opens them to the correct level.

The `set foldenable` method was not good, because if I choose to close one fold level, it enabled folding again, and folded every thing to 0 level, instead of just going down one level on the one I activated.