# Make Vim Spellcheck Work With Markdown Hash

Tags: vim, markdown

I've enabled vim spellchecking for markdown files.  It works fine when the file just contains plain text, but when I begin a file with an H1 hash like so

```
# My Title
```

spellchecking does not work. I assume that vim spell is treating this as a code comment and ignoring everything that follows. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Do you have a special plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was the result of having folding enabled for markdown using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842504/49359 .  I'm not exactly sure why, but removing this from my .vimrc solved the problem.